# JTabbedPane why is there extra padding only when I have multiple tabs? (code and picture)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabbed pane, which has a varying number of tabs.  When the number of tabs is greater than 4, I get extra spacing/padding at the bottom of each tab panel.  The picture below shows this (on the left you see the extra spacing, on the right you see no extra spacing).

[image]

Here is the exact code I used to get those pictures:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class DialogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DialogTest();
    }

    public DialogTest() {
        JDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyDialog extends JDialog {

        public MyDialog() {
            super(null, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            final JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
            final int numTabs = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of tabs:"));

            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

            for (int i = 1; i <= numTabs; i++) {
                tabs.addTab("Tab"+i, new MyPanel(i));
            }

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(tabs, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel(int text) {
            final JLabel label = new JLabel("THIS IS A PANEL" + text);
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(18f));
            label.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            label.setOpaque(true);

            add(label);
            setBackground(Color.red);
        }   
    }
}
```

I've tried numerous things including many different layout managers.  I can't for the life of me get rid of that extra spacing.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
tabs.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT); // ADD THIS!
```

The reason the other example behaves as it does is that the pane wraps the tabs to the next line & presumes that once we have gone beyond as many tabs as it might naturally display in a single line, it must increase the preferred size to include that extra line of tabs.

Comment: You're welcome.  Good work on posting an SSCCE of the problem.  That made it very easy to run it, see the problem and test my solution.  :)

Comment: This forces the tabs to form a single row, though.

Is there a way to have more than one row of tabs, while avoiding the extra spacing/padding at the bottom?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. *"Is there a way to.."* Good question (which deserves its own question thread, if not already asked & answered hereabouts).