# JTabbedPane how to have multiple rows of tabs, without the extra spacing/padding at the bottom of each tab panel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

Sort of a follow-up to [JTabbedPane why is there extra padding only when I have multiple tabs? (code and picture)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143362/jtabbedpane-why-is-there-extra-padding-only-when-i-have-multiple-tabs-code-and)

I have a lot of tabs, so I would prefer to have multiple rows of tabs to avoid excessive scrolling. This makes the SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT undesirable, as it creates a single row of tabs (shown in left image).

Using WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT lets me have multiple rows of tabs. However, I get extra space at the bottom of each tab panel (show by the large red area in right image).

[image: Panel on left has only 1 row, panel on right has extra padding]

Is there a way to get multiple rows of tabs, without the ugly extra spaces of WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT?

Here is some code to create the JTabbedPane. With a large number of tabs (20+), neither layout is satisfactory.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class DialogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DialogTest();
    }

    public DialogTest() {
        JDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyDialog extends JDialog {

        public MyDialog() {
            super(null, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            final JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
            tabs.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT); // change to WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT for other layout
            final int numTabs = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of tabs:"));

            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

            for (int i = 1; i <= numTabs; i++) {
                tabs.addTab("Tab"+i, new MyPanel(i));
            }

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(tabs, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel(int text) {
            final JLabel label = new JLabel("THIS IS A PANEL" + text);
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(18f));
            label.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            label.setOpaque(true);

            add(label);
            setBackground(Color.red);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you were asking about in a comment elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is (from the linked post).

Comment: More relevant information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944950/size-issues-with-jtabbedpane-and-fixed-height-content

Comment: Is there a need to add this to `BorderLayout.NORTH`? That is causing some of the effects you see.

Answer (score 1):

By setting a size to the `JDialog` you define an area that need to be filled by the components added to it. 
It seems that you need the area to be defined by the content of the `JDialog`, so the first think is to remove `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));` and let the layout manager define the appropriate size.

Next you need to set the content (`MyPanel`) to the desired size and layout, by using its layout manager. In the following MRE `GridBagLayout` is used for this purpose:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class DialogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DialogTest();
    }

    public DialogTest() {
        JDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyDialog extends JDialog {

        public MyDialog() {

            super(null, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            final JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
            //tabs.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
            tabs.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {  //12 as an arbitrary test value
                tabs.addTab("Tab"+i, new MyPanel(i));
            }

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(tabs, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        public MyPanel(int text) {

            final JLabel label = new JLabel("THIS IS A PANEL" + text);
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(18f));
            label.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            label.setOpaque(true);

            setBackground(Color.RED);
            GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
            gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{400, 0}; //affects parent width 
            gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{100, 0};   //affects parent height
            gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            setLayout(gridBagLayout);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(label, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]